# Proportional Control Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working on a boiler project in matlab with a partner. We are still new to this program and are currently working on the proportional control part of the boiler program. As a result we get 3 graphs like we are supposed to but we keep getting a mysterious dip on our center graph as seen below. Any diagnosis to the problem on how we can get rid of the dip is what we have been trying to figure out.

Here is our code:

```
clear all;
close all;

endtime=60;
time=0;
ResPer=0.05; %declares basic functions
setpoint=7;
flowrate=2.4;
valveposition=0.2;

delay=5;
timeaxis=[1:endtime];
valveaxis=0;   %declares arrays related to time and graphing
steamaxis=0;

propconstant=0.25;
RelError=0;    %declares arrays regarding the proportional controller
desiredvalve=0.5823;

while time<endtime

    %RelError=SteamRelativeError(flowrate, setpoint);
    %calculates the Relative Error used in the rest of the function

    if (time <= delay)

        valveposition=0.75*valveposition+0.25*(desiredvalve-propconstant*RelError); 
        %deals with the valve position before the time exceeds the delay
        %valveaxis(time)=valveposition;

    else

        valveaxis(time-delay)=0.75*valveposition+0.25*(desiredvalve-propconstant*RelError); %calculates and stores valve position after the delay has been passed

    end

    RelError=SteamRelativeError(flowrate, setpoint); %calculates the Relative Error used in the rest of the function

    time=time+1; %increments time

    flowrate=ValvePerToFlowRate(valveposition); %calculates flow rate from valve position

    valveaxis(time)=valveposition; %stores temporary valve position
    steamaxis(time)=flowrate; %stores steam flow rate
    erroraxis(time)=RelError; %stores the Relative Error

end


subplot(3,1,2), plot(timeaxis, valveaxis, 'b'); axis([0 endtime 0.2 0.8]); 
xlabel('Time(min)'); ylabel('Valve%');
subplot(3,1,1), plot(timeaxis, steamaxis, 'b'); axis([0 endtime 2 
setpoint+2]); xlabel('Time(min)'); ylabel('Steam mass flow rate (lbm/s)');
title('Proportional Constant=0.25'); %graphs functions
subplot(3,1,3), plot(timeaxis, erroraxis, 'b'); axis([0 endtime -0.6 0.2]); 
xlabel('Time(min)'); ylabel('Error');
```

And here are our graphs:

[image: Graphs]

Comment: I formatted and indented your code, and removed some spurious linebreaks in comments that seemed incorrect. Please inspect the code to ensure that I didn't accidentally break anything. (I probably should have added some linebreaks in the bottom part as well.)

Answer (score 0):

The dip is occurring because you set `valveaxis` in two difference places. In your `if else` block you set it to:

```
valveaxis(time-delay)=0.75*valveposition+0.25*(desiredvalve-propconstant*RelError);
```

However outside of this block you set it to:

```
valveaxis(time)=valveposition;
```

At each `time` the `valveaxis` is set using the second equation, only to be overwritten by the first formula `delay` iterations later. The very last values will not get overwritten since you break at `time==60`, so `valveaxis(54)` will be the last value set by the first formula. This is why your dip occurs between the 54th and 55th values.

Comment: Thank you for helping with the graph, we did that after getting feedback and never thought much of the override problem but it worked.